# MPV Player automatically pause after long run

Tags: linux, electron, media-player, media, mpv

I have implemented Linux player using **MPV player** [npm package mpv-controller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpv-controller).

I want to loop the video for a long time. Initially it's working fine up to 6 hours(approx). Then the video automatically paused.

While I investigate there is no memory issue, MPV player using very small amount of memory.

Please help me to fix this issue.

```
import mpv from 'mpv-controller';

this.mpvPlayer = new mpv(status => {
  console.log(status);
});
this.mpvPlayer.play(~/Downloads/sample.mp4, ["--no-border", "--no-window-dragging", "--no-osc", "--no-osd-bar", "--no-input-default-bindings", "--loop", "--ontop", "--hwdec=vaapi", "-vo", "vaapi", "--no-keepaspect", "--geometry=523x294-1397-786");
```

The above code is equivalent to

```
mpv ~/Downloads/sample.mp4  --no-border --no-window-dragging --no-osc --no-osd-bar --no-input-default-bindings --loop --ontop --hwdec=vaapi -vo vaapi --no-keepaspect --geometry=523x294-1397-786
```

**dependency**

You need to install mpv player first

```
sudo apt-get install mpv
```

Thank you.

Comment: An interesting problem, but don't expect readers to download your code to test the problem. Did you read [mcve] ? You should edit your Q to follow those guidelines. Good that you checked your memory, but are you watching before it hangs, or only after? Without looking at your code, and assuming there is not a condition in a while loop that is being triggered, I would add debug output inside of `mpv-controller` to see that all variable values are working as you intend. Good luck.

Comment: Have you solved it? I've encountered `mpv` failing after 6 hours when watching a long conference stream but it was due to the video URL expiring and simply adding `--loop-playlist` took care of that as it restarted the stream. I find it peculiar to see this 6 hours period again in a different context.

Comment: I have solved this issue using open mpv player using child_process with required args